# How to choose/connect the appropriate MOSFET-driver for a power MOSFET? Driver breaks down

Tags: circuit-design, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I'm quite new to using electronics, so maybe you can tell me what I am doing wrong.
I'm trying to drive a power MOSFET which will switch ~20 A, 50 V for 10 ms on, 490 ms off. At the moment I am using this one: IXTH80N65X2 (https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/IXYS/IXTH80N65X2?qs=gQEZvVdd8GtfX0OAe9oBtQ%3D%3D) I know that the pulse with that power is probably a bit too long for this MOSFET, but so far I didn´t run into problems with it.
The MOSFET driver I use MCP14E10-E/P (https://www.reichelt.de/3-0-a-dual-mosfet-treiber-2-x-nicht-invertierend-dip-8-mcp-14e10-e-p-p109723.html?&trstct=pol_14&nbc=1) is driven by an acquisition card and works fine, but only if the power MOSFET is used at low powers, around 20 V. If the power the MOSFET is supposed to switch is increased, the MOSFET driver breaks down. (It is getting hot, and I can see a constant current at the Vdd pin, although it is not supposed to be turned on). Why does the power the MOSFET driver switches, influences the MOSFET driver? I thought the MOSFET driver, shouldn´t be effected by this?
Here a picture of the MOSFET driver layout. I connected all grounds (pin 3, Source of power-MOSFET, acquisition card and power source). Pin 2 (In A) is connect to the logic signal of the card. Out A is connected to the gate of the power MOSFET. Can anyone tell me, if I need some extra modules for this kind of power? Is the Gate of the MOSFET requiring more energy, if it is supposed to switch higher Powers and is it "too much" for the MOSFET driver.

Thanks in advance

[image: Mosfet-driver]

This is the physical layout
[image: physical layout of mosfet switch]

Comment: What's Vdd connected to?

Comment: Welcome! Please post schematic and layout.

Comment: i added the layout, hope this helps

Comment: I don’t see any PCB layout. Post a screenshot from your E-CAD or a photo of your PCB.

Answer (score 2):

The physical layout of the entire system is very important. You’re switching high enough currents, fast enough to make parasitic inductances act like automotive ignition coils. If you post the layout and schematics, someone should be able to spot all the problems. There usually is more than one.